# Uncaught TypeError: handler.apply is not a function (webpack-internal) with Vue/Rails/Cypress

Tags: docker, vue.js, cypress

So I'm working on a Vue/Rails application that's using GraphQL with Cypress in the frontend for testing the GUI.

Whenever I break out my it blocks for testing the code I receive the following error:

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: handler.apply is not a function (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:63)

For example THIS works:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
context('Admin > Routes', function () {
  describe('Create Route', function () {
    // beforeEach(() => {
    //   cy.fixture("admin/route").as("route");
    // })
    it('Clicks New Route', function () {
      cy.admin_login();
      cy.get('.dashboard-link:nth-child(3)')
        .click().wait(1000)
      cy.get('.v-toolbar .v-tooltip--bottom')
        .find('a').first().click()
      cy.get('[aria-label="Route Name"]')
        .type("Here")
        .should('have.value', 'Here')
    })
    })
```

THIS causes the error:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
context('Admin > Routes', function () {
  describe('Create Route', function () {
    // beforeEach(() => {
    //   cy.fixture("admin/route").as("route");
    // })
    it('Clicks New Route', function () {
      cy.admin_login();
      cy.get('.dashboard-link:nth-child(3)')
        .click().wait(1000)
      cy.get('.v-toolbar .v-tooltip--bottom')
        .find('a').first().click()
    })
    it('Enters Route Name', function () {
      cy.get('[aria-label="Route Name"]')
        .type("Here")
        .should('have.value', 'Here')
    })
  })
```

From my console I get all of this:
[image: Console output]

I thought it might be a docker issue. So I did:

- docker-compose down, then docker-compose build/docker-compose up
- docker-compose restart, docker-compose build/docker-compose up
- docker restart $(docker ps -q), docker-compose build/docker-compose
  up

I wasn't too super into the Cypress tests so I went extreme and went "screw it...I'll start from scratch". So I deleted the local repo, re-cloned the repo, reinstalled cypress. From cypress just added the baseUrl, added in the command for admin_login, built the basic test. At this point no clue what the issue is for me to fix.